# jQuery default/placeholder input text and problems with saved information

Tags: jquery, css, authentication, autocomplete, input

I'm new to jQuery and have an annoying problem.
I have some login fields that are filled with default text when the field is empty and then removed when clicked.

My problem is that when the user has their username/password saved (with browser), if they return to the page the login fields are filled with the users saved input as well as the default input.

```
$('#login input.text').each(function(i, field) {
            field = $(field);
            if (field.val().length > 0) {
                field.prev().css('display', 'none');
            }
            field.focus(function() {
                field.prev().css('display', 'none');
            }).blur(function() {
                if (field.val() == '') field.prev().css('display', 'block');
            });
        })
```

Comment: Do you want to stop the browser from autocompleting the fields, or to hide field.prev() if the browser does autocomplete?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the html5 placeholder attribute.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
```

Mike Taylor has written a great jQuery plugin to support browsers that don't support this attribute yet. http://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

i would go for something like this for having default values instead of showing hiding something next to fields. Of course you can use any custom attribute instead of name but having login and password seems to be fine:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#login input.text').each(function() {
        var field = $(this);
        if (!!field.val() && field.val() !=field.attr('name')) {
            field.val(field.attr('name'));
        }
    }).focus(function() {
        var field = $(this);
        if (field.val() == field.attr('name')) field.val('');
    }).blur(function() {
        var field = $(this);
        if (!!field.val()) field.val(field.attr('name'));
    });
```

});